# jquery datepicker ui - lose hover after next previous

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, hover

I have a datepicker setup as inline. The idea I have is the selected days and when you hover over a tooltip pops up and shows the title of the events.

The issue I am having is when skipping to the next month, the hover stops working, and when I click back the ones on the default (current) month do not work either.

In the example http://jsfiddle.net/welovedesign/rn67L/ there are events on the 1st and 11th of August and the 11th of September

Answer (score 0):

When the calendar is created, only the dates for the current month are rendered. This is why when you click to another month that therre is no `div` appearing when you hover over a date with an event.

In the `onChangeMonthYear` event you'll need to create your div for a date where there is an event and associate it with the appropiate date (as you are doing in the `beforeShowDay` event).